# Android: Install another app and detect when it is launched the first time

Tags: android, installation, android-package-managers, activity-manager, android-activitymanager

I have an application that installs other applications, just like Google Play Store. To complete the chain of analytics, I need to be able to detect when the apps installed are launched the first time.

Google Play Store definitely has it implemented in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android system does that for you. The package manager broadcasts [`Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH`](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#2126) to the installer when an installed application is launched for the first time. To make sure you receive it, you need to:

- Set the installer package name as soon as you install the application, as the broadcast is restricted to the installer package name set for the application being launched.

  ```
  getPackageManager().setInstallerPackageName("com.example", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
  ```
- Make sure you are not using [`PackageManager.INSTALL_REPLACE_EXISTING`](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java#576), as it will be assumed to be an update, for which the broadcast is not sent by the system
- Register your receiver for action [`Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH`](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#2126) at runtime and not in the manifest.

Registering the broadcast receiver:

```
registerReceiver(new LaunchReceiver(), new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH));
```

Sample broadcast receiver:

```
public class LaunchReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getData() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Package name: " + intent.getDataString().replace("package:", ""));
        }
    }
}
```

For more information, read the actual code here: [`PackageManagerService.notifyFirstLaunch()`](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java#12483)

Comment: Do you know what is correct way to 'Set the installer package name as soon as you install the application' ?